# complete.cases and data.frames with POSIXlt

Tags: r

I am primarily a Python programmer by trade, but am still learning R.  The data I am having an issue with is available [here](https://github.com/rdpeng/RepData_PeerAssessment1), but I have made a small example of the issue, below.

R's `complete.cases()` function should return a logical vector indicating which rows of the tested object(s) contain no NA values.

```
df <- data.frame(val1=c(1, 2, NA, 4),
                 val2=c("12:00", "10:30", "09:15", "05:00"))
print(df)
##   val1  val2
## 1    1 12:00
## 2    2 10:30
## 3   NA 09:15
## 4    4 05:00

print(length(df$val1) == length(df$val2))
## [1] TRUE

complete.cases(df)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

This works as expected: one `False` value, corresponding to the `NA` value in `df$val1`.

---

I am running into an issue where, after I convert a character vector into a `POSIXlt` vector via `strptime`, `complete.cases` no longer works due to the following error:

`Error in complete.cases(df) : not all arguments have the same length`.

For example:

```
df$val2 <- strptime(df$val2, format="%H:%M")
print(df)
##   val1                val2
## 1    1 2015-01-14 12:00:00
## 2    2 2015-01-14 10:30:00
## 3   NA 2015-01-14 09:15:00
## 4    4 2015-01-14 05:00:00

print(length(df$val1) == length(df$val2))
## [1] TRUE

complete.cases(df)  # This line now causes the error.
```

As you can see, the length of `df$val1` and `df$val2` are still the same.  Am I missing something here?  Why would `complete.cases` stop working after I converted the time-strings with `strptime`?

I'm sure I can work around this particular issue (I don't *really* need the data converted via `strptime`), I'm just curious why `complete.cases` is not working for me.

---

System info:

- R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me"
- R Studio Version 0.98.1087
- Windows 7

Comment: I saw the question title and thought "oh gawd, POSIXlt and data.frames,... this can't be good." I don't know the "why"-answer in this particular situation, but there is an R rule: 'Never use POSIXlt in dataframes.'

Comment: `df$val2 <- as.POSIXct(df$val2, format="%H:%M")` is what you probably want instead.  POSIXlt values are lists underneath. `complete.cases` works with this

Comment: 'Never use POSIXlt in dataframes.' -- That is remarkably good to know, thank you.

Comment: Richard, looks like you've fixed the issue.  Thank you much.  I'll do some reading on the various POSIX types so I can better understand what's going on, but for the time being, I can move forward.

Comment: @ZacharyCross - Very clear and well presented question, btw

Comment: @RichardScriven - Thanks!  Trying to make it easy for people like you to help me learn.  Thanks again for the clear answer that you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strptime()` produces POSIXlt values, which are lists underneath. This is what is giving you problems.

```
df <- data.frame(
    val1 = c(1, 2, NA, 4),
    val2 = c("12:00", "10:30", "09:15", "05:00")
)
df$val2 <- strptime(df$val2, format="%H:%M")
is.list(df$val2)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Side note: If your intention with `complete.cases()` is to subset the data,  `na.omit(df)` will work with the POSIXlt values.

---

As @BondedDust notes, you should stay away from using POSIXlt values in data frames if you can.  But we can use POSIXct values, which are just integers underneath, and `complete.cases()` works just fine.

Beginning with your original `df` again...

```
df <- data.frame(
    val1 = c(1, 2, NA, 4),
    val2 = c("12:00", "10:30", "09:15", "05:00")
)
df$val2 <- as.POSIXct(df$val2, format="%H:%M")
complete.cases(df)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Also, if you check the `unclass()` values for each of these `df$val2`'s, the difference will become quite obvious.

Comment: `df[!do.call(mapply, c(any,lapply(df,is.na))),]` works if for some archaic reason you are bound to `POSIXlt`.

Comment: @thelatemail - thankfully I'm not tied to POSIXlt; I was just using strptime() because that's how I would have done it in Python; still learning how to *think* in R, rather than just 'do Python stuff in R'.